# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: How map object with array field in React JS to Java object?

Tags: json, reactjs, spring, rest, type-mismatch

When I make request from client-side to server-side I pass object which have field with array. On the server side I get this type of error message:

```
Failed to read HTTP message: 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON 
parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.example.dto.TopicDto` 
out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot 
deserialize instance of `com.example.dto.TopicDto` out of START_ARRAY token
```

How can I map this object to Java POJO ? Should I use JSON.stringify() or JSON.parse() method on this object at client-side ?

Before I got error: Required request body is missing.

My code below:

```
@Controller
public class TopicController {

@PostMapping(name = "/topic/{forumType}/{jwtToken}")
public ResponseEntity<?> addTopicToForum(@RequestBody TopicDto topicDto, @PathVariable String forumType,
                                         @PathVariable String jwtToken) {
}
}
```

TopicDto class:

```
public class TopicDto {

private String title;
private String message;
private int likes;
private String languageForum;
private List<FileDto> files;
// getters and setters, no constructors
}
```

FileDto class

```
public class FileDto {

private String objectId;
private String url;
private Long size;
private String name;
private String type;
// getters and setters, no constructors
}
```

Client-side

```
class AddTopic extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        title: '',
        message: '',
        isInvalidTitle: false,
        isInvalidMessage: false,
        successFiles: [],
        successNameFiles: [],
        isSuccessUploaded: false,
        isFailureUploaded: false,
        failureNameFiles: []
    }
    this.onSubmitForm = this.onSubmitForm.bind(this);
    this.responseFilestack = this.responseFilestack.bind(this);
}

onSubmitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.validateForm(e);

    if(this.errors.length === 0) {
        let jwtToken = localStorage.getItem("JwtToken");
        let forumType = this.props.match.params.selectedForum;

        const topicDto = {
            title: this.state.title,
            message: this.state.message,
            likes: "0",
            languageForum: forumType,
            files: this.state.successFiles
        }

        fetch(`/topic/${forumType}/${jwtToken}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: topicDto,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
    }
}

responseFilestack(response) {
    response.filesUploaded.map((file, index) => {
        const element = {
            objectId: file.uploadId,
            url: file.url,
            size: file.size,
            name: file.originalFile.name,
            type: file.originalFile.type
        };
        this.setState({ 
            successFiles: this.state.successFiles.concat(element),
            successNameFiles: this.state.successNameFiles.concat(file.originalFile.name),
            isSuccessUploaded: true
        });
    });
}
}
```

UPDATE: [image: request body]

Comment: `likes: "0"` return value like a string, but you expect int

Comment: Please attach your request body instead of javascript code

Comment: What is this request body what you want ? This is photo which I appended ? I changed on likes: 0 instead of likes: "0" and is the same error as in title

Comment: RequestBody is something you attach along with the request. If you click on preview tab you will see JSON there. That will help to identify the issue.

Comment: Preview tab is empty

Comment: That's what your error is... You have to supply JSON with `TopicDto`, but your body is empty

Comment: How do that in my case ?